# Azure subscription changing company

Tags: azure, entra-id, subscription

I have been assigned an Enterprise subscription by my company. I used it from my personal Microsoft account.

If I leave, what will happen to my subscription and resources in Azure?

Does the subscription stay permanently with me or will my employer be able to withdraw it?

And if they can withdraw it, what happens to the resources in my subscription?

Do they get wiped out? deactivated? can they be transferred to a new sub if I get a new one from a new employer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a sub under an Enterprise Agreement, then this belongs to your employer, you are just allocated access to this subscription. If you leave, your account will be removed from having access.

If you wanted to move the subscription or resources when you leave, this can be done, but it would need to be approved by your employer, as they are the one paying the bill and having ultimate control.